# Ближайший объект по вводимому в строке поиска адресу на Яндекс Картах

Tags: yandex-maps-api

не нашёл вроде ответа на такой ворпос, может знает кто-то)
https://medsi.ru/ вот здесь реальзовано.
вводишь свой адрес и тебе показывают ближайший к тебе филиал организации (из тметок, что есть на карте).
как такое реализвать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Алгоритм должен быть примерно таким:

1. Реализовать для карты собственное поисковое поле удобным вам методом.
2. [Геокодировать](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/geocode.html) введённый в поле адрес.
3. Выполнить перебором [определение дистанций](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/ICoordSystem.html#method_detail__getDistance) от полученных координат до всех координат филиалов.
4. Отсортировать полученные результаты и вывести информацию о ближайшем объекте опять же удобным вам методом.

Comment: Доброго времени. спасибо, но там проще всё на самом деле, есть функция getClosestTo и у него уже balloon.open

Comment: Верно, 3 и 4 пункты, если объекты добавлены на карту, можно заменить на https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/GeoQueryResult.html#method_detail__getClosestTo

Comment: да, всё верно, извиняюсь, я не совсем правильно сформулировал вопрос. объекты отмечены на карте, надо чтобы всплывали их балуны (точнее один, у ближайшего) после поиска.

Answer (score 0):

у меня в итоге выглядит (рабочий вариант) так:

```
         function geocode() {
      var request = $('#address').val();
     coord = ymaps.geocode(request);
     coord.then(
function (res) {
    
    var adcoord = res.geoObjects.get(0).geometry.getCoordinates();
         dent.getClosestTo(adcoord).balloon.open();
},
function (err) {
    alert('Пожалуйста уточните адрес');
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).